# Fieldsets estão quebrando no Chrome, mas não no IE

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Tenho uns `Fieldsets` que quando exibidos no `Chrome`, eles aparecem um em baixo do outro, que na verdade deveriam estar um ao lado do outro. Isso, de aparecer um ao lado do outro, só acontece no `IE`. No `Chrome`, quebra todo layout. Abaixo o código completo do `Fieldset` e as `tables` criadas dentro dele. Tudo está dentro de uma `tag` `<form>`

```
<fieldset id="fieldsetGeral">
<legend></legend>
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
   <td valign="top" class="label_left">
      <%Response.write logo_produto_saude%>
      <%Response.write logo_produto_dental%>
   </td>
   <td valign="top" class="label_left" colspan="2" nowrap>
      <fieldset style="width: 1px"><legend class="label_center">&nbsp;Básico&nbsp;</legend>&nbsp;
         <img id="img_icoativoexcluidocontrato" src="\gen\img\<%if ind_situacao = "A" then response.write "icoAtivo.png?" & Day(date) else if ind_situacao = "E" then response.write "icoExcluido.png?" & Day(date) else response.write "icoInadimplente.gif?" & Day(date) end if end if%>" alt="<%if ind_situacao = "A" then response.write "Contrato Ativo" else if ind_situacao = "E" then response.write "Contrato Excluído em " & data_fim_vigencia else response.write "Contrato Inadimplente" end if end if%>">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset style="width: 1px"><legend class="label_center">&nbsp;Flags&nbsp;</legend>
            &nbsp;
            <% 
            if trim(nom_imagem_flag_atd_se) <> "" then
               %>
               <img src="\gen\img\<%Response.write nom_imagem_flag_atd_se%>?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="<%Response.write nome_situacao_esp%>">
               <% 
            end if

            if trim(nom_imagem_flag_atd_om) <> "" then
               %>
               <img src="\gen\img\<%Response.write nom_imagem_flag_atd_om%>?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="<%Response.write nom_marca%>"> 
               <% 
            end if
            %>
            <img src="\gen\img\<%if flag_tem_ocorrencia then response.write "icoOcorrencia.png?" & Day(date) else response.write "icoOcorrencia_cinza.png?" & Day(date)%>" alt="<%if flag_tem_ocorrencia then response.write "Existem mensagens para consultar"%>" onclick="<%if flag_tem_ocorrencia then response.write "chamaOcorrencia();"%>" <%if flag_tem_ocorrencia then response.write "style='cursor:hand'" %>>
            <%
            if ind_efaturamento = "S" then
               %>                
               <img id="img_efaturamento" src="\gen\img\ico_efaturamento.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Contrato faz parte do Faturamento on-line desde <%Response.write dt_ini_efaturamento%>" onclick="abrirEfaturamento();" style='cursor:hand'>
               <% 
            else    
               %>
               <img id="img_efaturamento" src="\gen\img\ico_efaturamento_cinza.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>">
               <%
            end if
            %>
            <img id="img_valor" <%if txt_msg_atraso = "" then response.write "style='display:none'"%> src="\gen\img\icoValores_vermelho.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="<%Response.write txt_msg_atraso%>" onclick="carregaCadeiaPagamento();" style='cursor:hand'>
            <%    
            if flag_tem_atd then
               %>
               <img id="img_protocolos_atd" src="\gen\img\icoProtocolos.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Existe protocolo para consultar" onclick="chamaOcorrenciaAtendimento();" style='cursor:hand'>
               <% 
            else
               %>
               <img id="img_protocolos_atd" src="\gen\img\icoProtocolos_cinza.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Não existem protocolos para consultar" onclick="chamaOcorrenciaAtendimento();">
               <%
            end if
            if buscarcaaberto ( session("atc_xml_rca") ) = "1" then 
               %>
               <img id="img1" src="\gen\img\icons\EmExecucao.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Existem Workflows pendentes" onclick="chamaOcorrenciaAtendimento();" style='cursor:hand'>
               <%
            end if
            if flag_possui_acesso_acao_jud then
               %>
               <img src="\gen\img\icons\balanca_vermelha.gif?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt='Consulta ação judicial' onclick='abreAcaoJudicial()' style='cursor:hand'>
               <%
            end if
            if flag_dir_especial_legado then
               %>
               <img src="\gen\img\informacao.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Exibe Direitos Especiais" onclick="exibeDadosDirEspecial('','<%Response.write num_contrato%>','ATC')" style='cursor:hand'> 
               <%
            end if
            if ind_forma_exibicao = "1" or ind_forma_exibicao = "2"  then
               %>                        
               <img src="\gen\img\atd_aviso_msg.gif?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Contrato possui mensagens" onclick="exibeMensagemAtd()" style='cursor:hand' width='20' height='20'>
               <%
            end if
            %>
            &nbsp;
      </fieldset>
   </td>  
   <td valign="center" class="label_center">
      <div id="divProtocolo" style="display:none" nowrap align="right">  
            Protocolo&nbsp;<span id="spanNumProtocolo"></span>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="label_right">
      <%
      'Quando estiver vindo do Atendimento Beneficiário o "CERTO" é manter o botão invisível
      'Para manter o botão invisível, devemos realizar testes com a função trataCarregamento()
      'pois a mesma gera erro se o botão não estiver visível.
      if ind_origem_consulta = "A" then 
            %>
            <img src="../../gen/img/abrir_atendimento.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" style="display:none;cursor:pointer" id="linkAbrirAtendimento" width="135px" height="25px" onclick="abrirAtendimento();">
            <img src="../../gen/img/encerrar_atendimento.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" style="display:none;cursor:pointer" id="linkEncerrarAtd" width="150px" height="25px" onclick="exibeCamposEncerramento();">
            <%
      end if 
      %>        
   </td>     
</tr>
</table>
<div id="" style='display:'><%call montaDadosPrincipais()%></div>           
<table width="100%" border="0" id="tb_dvDadosBasicos" style="display:">
    <tr>
        <td class="label_right" ><img id="img_dvDadosBasicos" src="../../gen/img/btn-up.jpg?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" width="16" height="12" onClick="ExpandirFrame('dvDadosBasicos');" style="cursor:hand" title="Clique para exibir informações" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="dvDadosBasicos" style='display:'><%call montaDadosBasicos()%></div>
<%
sub montaDadosPrincipais()
    %>
    <table border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>            
            <td width="15%" class="label_right"><%Response.write txt_label_sucursal%>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="30%" class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write nome_sucursal%></b>
            </td>
            <td width="15%" class="label_right"><%Response.write txt_label_inspetoria%>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="12%" class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write nome_inspetoria%></b>
            </td>        
            <td width="15%" class="label_right">Empresa Mãe&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <label title="<%Response.write nome_empresa_mae%>">
                    <b><%Response.write num_contrato_mae%>&nbsp;</b>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right">Venda&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write dt_venda%></b>
            </td>
            <td class="label_right">Vencimento&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write dia_pagamento%></b>
            </td>            
            <% 
            if (num_seq_proposta_pj_ts <> "") or (num_seq_contrato_pji_ts <> "") then
                %>
                <td class="label_right">Proposta&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                    <% 
                    if trim(num_seq_proposta_pj_ts) <> "" then 
                        %>
                        <a href="javascript:pesquisaPropostaPME('<%=num_proposta%>','<%=num_seq_proposta_pj_ts%>');" title="Consultar Proposta"><b><%Response.write num_proposta%></b></a>
                        <%
                    elseif trim(num_seq_contrato_pji_ts) <> "" then 
                        %>
                        <a href="javascript:pesquisaPropostaPJI('<%=num_seq_contrato_pji_ts%>','<%=cod_produtor_ts%>');" title="Consultar Proposta"><b><%Response.write num_seq_contrato_pji_ts%></b></a>
                        <%
                    end if
                    %>                            
                </td>
                <% 
            end if
            %>            
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right">Contrato&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <label title="<%if ind_regulamentado = "Sim" then response.write "Regulamentado" else response.write "Não Regulamentado" end if%><%if trim(data_adaptacao) <> "" then response.write "&#13Data de Adaptação " & data_adaptacao end if%>"><font color="red"><b><%Response.write num_contrato%></b>&nbsp;<b><%Response.write nome_entidade%></b></font></label>
                <img src="\gen\img\gif\telefone.gif?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Contatos" onclick="carregaContatos()" style="cursor:hand">
            </td>   
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Porte Contrato&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write nome_tipo_empresa%></b>
            </td>              
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Contrato Padrão&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><a href="#" onclick="retornaUrlContratoAmpliado()" title="" style="cursor:hand"><%Response.write cod_contrato_ampliado%></a></b>
                <%
                if cod_contrato_ampliado <> "" then
                    %>
                    <img src="\gen\img\email.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" alt="Envio de Email Contrato Padrão" style="cursor:hand" onclick="carregaDadosEmail('','<%=cod_ts_contrato%>','<%=cod_entidade_ts%>','<%=nome_entidade%>','ATD_EMAIL_CONTRATO','<%Response.write txt_protocolo_atendimento%>','<%Response.write cod_contrato_ampliado%>');">
                    <%                                                                                                                
                end if
                %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%
end sub

sub montaDadosBasicos()
    %>
    <table border="0" width="100%">                 
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right">C.N.P.J.&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write num_cgc%></b>&nbsp;<label title='<%Response.write "Razão Social"%>'><b><%Response.write nome_razao_social%></b></label>
            </td>            
            <%
            if tipo_empresa = "6" then
                %>
                <td class="label_right" nowrap>Administradora&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                    <b><%Response.write cod_corretor%>&nbsp;<%Response.write nome_corretor%></b>
                </td>
                <%
            else
                %>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <%
            end if    
            %>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Insc. Estadual&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write num_inscr_estadual%></b>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Tipo Contrato&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write nome_tipo_contrato%></b>
            </td>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Grupo Contrato&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write nome_grupo_empresa%></b>
            </td>            
            <td class="label_right">Situação&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <span id="spanlblsituacao">
                   <% 
                   if ind_situacao = "E" then
                      %>
                      <font color="white" style="background-color:#FF0000"><b><%Response.write nom_situacao%></b></font>
                      <% 
                   else    
                      %>
                      <font color="red"><b><%Response.write nom_situacao%></b></font>
                      <% 
                   end if    
                   %>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Início Vigência&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <span id="spanlbldatainiciovigencia"><b><%Response.write data_inicio_vigencia%></b></span>
            </td>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Fim Vigência&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap >
                <span id="spanlbldatafimvigencia"><font color="white" style="background-color:#FF0000"><b><%Response.write data_fim_vigencia%></b></font></span>
            </td>
            <td class="label_right">Negociação&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write txt_dt_negociacao%></b>
            </td>            
        </tr>                  
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Dias Inadimplência&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <%
                if dias_inadimplencia <> "0" then
                    %>
                    <span id="spanlbldiasinadimplencia"><b><%Response.write dias_inadimplencia%></b></span>
                    <%
                end if
                %>
            </td>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Data Inadimplência&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <span id="spanlbldatainadimplencia"><b><%Response.write data_inadimplencia%></b></span>
            </td>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Sit. Inadimplência&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap >
                <span id="spanlblsituacaoinadimplencia">
                   <font color="white" style="background-color:#FF0000"><b><%Response.write nom_situacao_inadimp%></b></font>
                </span>
            </td>            
        </tr>                  
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right" nowrap>Atividade Econômica&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap colspan=3>
                <label title="<%Response.write nome_atividade%>">
                <%
                if nome_atividade <> "" then
                    %>
                    <b> <%Response.write txt_nome_atividade%>... </b>
                    <%
                end if
                %>
                </label>
            </td>  
            <td class="label_right">Tel.Cobrança&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <%
                if num_fax <> "" then
                    %>
                    <label title="<%Response.write txt_telefone%>"><b>(<%Response.write num_ddd_telefone_1%>)&nbsp;<%Response.write num_telefone_1%></b></label>
                    <%
                end if
                %>
            </td>             
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right">Qualificação&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap colspan=3>
                <b><%Response.write desc_qualificacao_empresa%></b>
            </td> 
            <td class="label_right">Tel.Fax&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <%
                if num_fax <> "" then
                    %>
                    <b>(<%Response.write num_ddd_fax%>)&nbsp;<%Response.write num_fax%></b>
                    <%
                end if
                %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label_right">Gerente&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write txt_gerente%></b>
            </td>    
            <td class="label_right">Analista&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write txt_analista%></b>
            </td>
            <td class="label_right">Célula&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="label_left" nowrap>
                <b><%Response.write nom_equipe_vendas%></b>
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <% 
        if trim(data_adaptacao) <> "" and trim(ind_regulamentado) = "Sim" then
            %>
            <tr>
                <td valign="bottom" nowrap align="center" colspan="8">
                    <b><font color="white" style="background-color:#FF0000">&nbsp;&nbsp;Contrato Adaptado em <%Response.write data_adaptacao%>&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% 
        end if
        %>
    </table>
    <% 
end sub
%>
<table id="tbl_dados_encerramento" style="display:none">
    <br />
    <div id="divEncerramento" style="width:70%;margin-left:150px;display:none">
        <legend>
            <img src="../../gen/img/confirmar_encerramento.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" style="cursor:hand" id="linkConfirmarEncerramento" width="160px" height="25px" onclick="encerrarAtendimento();">
            <img src="../../gen/img/cancelar_encerramento_atendimento.png?<%Response.write Day(date)%>" style="cursor:hand" id="linkCancelarEncerramento" width="160px" height="25px" onclick="exibeCamposEncerramento();">
        </legend>        
    </div>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Importante. Os `Fieldsets` que estão quebrando são:

> Básico e Flags

.